# Using a zero-sized array in Visual Studio 2013 C++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2013, compiler-errors

Working on a rather large project which for reasons that are out of my control require that a zero-length array is used as a *pseudo*-pointer.

The array in question is defined in of the .hpp files in one of the structs:

```
    struct mail_t {
        custom_enum_t  src;
        custom_enum_t  dest;
        uint16_t  length;
        uint8_t  data[ ];
    };
```

The error is thrown where data[ ] is defined (substituting data[0] has no effect).

The project can compile on Ubuntu with gcc 7.1.0 no problem.

Any ideas for a fix to compile this project with Visual Studio? I'm open to suppressing compiler warning, importing other libraries etc.

Comment: That's not a zero-sized array, it's a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member), a feature that was added to C by the 1999 ISO standard. I'm not surprised if gcc implements it as an extension in C++. Since it's non-standard, I don't know whether it's possible to implement it in C++. Note that in C `data` is *not* a pointer; it's an array whose effective size is determined by how much memory is allocated for the structure.

Comment: Perhaps I should have clarified, in the code it is used the same way one would use a pointer. Let me edit my question to include how `data` is used later on.

Comment: Arrays and pointers are entirely distinct constructs. Suggested reading: section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/); most or all of it applies to C++ as well.

Answer (score 2):

Since C++ doesn't support [flexible array members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member), probably your best bet would be to use a "struct hack", the questionably legal feature that flexible array members were designed to replace.

Flexible array members were introduced in C99. Note that in your example, `data` is not a pointer. It's an array object whose effective size depends on the amount of memory allocated for the containing structure.

Using the struct hack, you could define the member as

```
uint8_t data[1];
```

That should get you past the compilation error. If you allocate extra memory for a `struct mail_t` object, you *might* be able to treat `data` as an array with a length greater than 1. But strictly speaking, accessing any element of `data` past element 0 has undefined behavior, and a compiler is free to take advantage of that fact for optimization purposes. (Since there's so much old code that uses the struct hack, C compilers typically avoid breaking it. I'm not sure whether that's also true of C++ compilers.)

An alternative might be to define `data` with a length at least as large as the number of elements you're going to access, and then allocate *fewer* that `sizeof (struct mail_t)` bytes to hold a structure. That might also run into undefined behavior, but my guess is that it's a bit more likely to "work".

(The right solution, of course, is to use a different data structure, perhaps a pointer pointing to a separately allocated array, or one of C++'s many container classes.)

The struct hack is discussed in question 2.6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: "The right solution is to use a different data structure" --> Agreed (or another compiler).  If the compiler does not support a feature - any work-around is at some level, a hack.

Comment: @chux: Unfortunately, the "right solution" is not always available.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, I agree using a different data structure is the correct answer, but this is code written in C that I am bringing to Windows in C++. Lots of bureaucracy behind it. I think using the struct hack and declaring it as `data[1]` and adapting other parts of the code as you suggest is the best solution.

Comment: My only concern is I cannot change the size of `data` since I cannot change the size (in bytes) of struct `mail_t`-- as `mail_t` is a message of a fixed size coming in.

Comment: @ducksinc: Your management should understand that C and C++ are two different languages. Not all valid C code is valid C++ code, and certainly not all valid C code is *good* C++ code. If you have valid C code, why not just continue compiling it as C?